# Irrespective selected values printed in the state of React.js | Material UI <Select> bug

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've tried to print the selected values via console.log but getting irrespective of selected value. Please help.
 Below is the code:

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
// import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";

class Shift extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      shift: ''
    };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ shift: e.target.value });
    console.log(this.state.shift);

    // this.props.handleChange(this.state.shift);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="shift">
        <center>
          <Select
            autoWidth={true}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value = {this.state.shift}

            displayEmpty
          >
            <MenuItem value=''
             disabled>
              Enter shift amount
            </MenuItem>

            {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(String).map(x => (
              <MenuItem key={x} value={x}>
                {x}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </center>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Shift;
```

Please run this code and provide me any feasible way. Thanks in  advance

Answer (score 0):

The `setState` does not guarantee that the value you set will be updated immediately. It only guarantees that the value will be available for the next rendering cycle.

If you want to use the value inside the `handleChange` (besides the `setState`) you should just save it inside a variable, and use it:

```
handleChange = e => {
    const newVal = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ shift: newVal });
    console.log( newVal );
    this.props.handleChange(newVal);
};
```

You can read more about this [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I've tried this method already and it works well. But the thing is in material ui select. If am not using material ui select, state value gets displayed properly on logs without using the local variable newVal also. Could you please suggest any idea about that?.. You can modify this code without  using material ui and see the output, hope you will understand.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You asked about material-ui, so the answer is about material-ui. Note that people spend their time on helping, and if the questions is not focused enough or "actually I mean something else" - this will probably not give you the answer you wanted.